# Mirror your display to another computer on your network

Tags: windows, networking, display, airplay, chromecast

I have a computer I am using for showing media, running windows 7 (XBMC). It is hooked up with a projector.

I want other computers on my network to have the opportunity to mirror their display to this computer.(without the media computer having to accept it, it should be all controlled by the sending computer.(like sending a movie with Apple's Airplay))

One scenario: 
I am finding a webpage with a great article (or a Word document) on my computer that i want to show to the other people in the room, i press a button, then my screen is mirrored to the media pc. I can still scroll, write etc. so everybody can see it. When i am done showing the article, I can exit the display mirroring, and the media computer display goes back to normal.

This should mirror the whole screen, not only the browser like plugins can do in chrome, or sending  Youtube movies like plugins for Opera.

**Update**

I found a video example of the solution I am looking for, unfortunately it looks like it will be hard [making a Chromecast reciever for windows.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845596/will-there-be-chromecast-receiver-emulator-or-an-alternate-app-that-acts-as-a-re)

Using the "Cast entire screen (experimentally)" button on the Chromecast plugin in Chrome is doing the exact thing I want to do, [see this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdTr3ho0X-A).

Comment: you could always use vlc, but that will be laggy with video, and may have issues with diffrant resolutions, etc. I've found in past that I need a hardware output splitter to do this (one hdmi in and many out, to both TVs or whatever. ) I could walk into any room in the house and the TV was already showing the anime I had queued up earlier.

Comment: As far as i know you have to chose a URL to receive the stream from when using VLC to send stream. This doesn't solve my question, I need a solution that pops up on the receiving computer without having to do any choices on it. For instance, the media computer is running XBMC, a computer on the LAN is sending a video/audio signals to the media computer, and when its done showing it, the media computer returns to xbmc.

Comment: well, vlc allows you to view and interact with the same desktop on both ends, so you can control the mouse cursor, type input, and view any open windows on both devices at the same time. you seem more interested in streaming specific content to devices than in actually mirroring your display on multiple machines.

Comment: What technology is used to send the image is not important. But I need the possibility to edit the content while its showing on the media computer, thats why I was thinking of a sort of mirroring, because i want exactly the same information on both computers, and it has to be editable from the sending computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TightProjector](http://www.tightvnc.com/projector/) from the makers of TightVNC *might* do what you want.

> TightProjector is a program that can transmit the screen of a particular Windows computer to other computers in the same local-area network. The data is transmitted continuously, in real time.
>
> In other words, you “project” a screen to other networked computers.

I dont know if it has the ability to bring up the cast automatically when started, but it might.

Comment: Thank you, TightVNC does exactly what im looking for. The only problem is that you need license for using it more than 20 minutes, wish there was a free alternative.

Comment: does this support multiple monitors?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use tightvnc and just remote into the computer you want to display from the computer with the projector connected. Easiest solution in my opinion with no need for license and little to no lag on a local network.

Comment: "The only problem is that you need license for using it more than 20 minutes, wish there was a free alternative."  – [klikkamongo, the OP](//superuser.com/users/230449/klikkamongo), over a year *before* you posted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

team viewer is free and work like you want it to work. You just have to install on both pc's and use the password. You can even use it on your smart phone and control the pc from your phone and you don't even have to be in the same network

Comment: Huh, say what, come again?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your PC into a Cast receiver using Google Cast for Education. For the full functionality of this Chrome app, you need Google Apps for Education, but for this basic functionality it should work fine. The trick is that you must be signed into Chrome on both computers using the same Google login information. Then you can stream from your other PC to the media PC using the functionality built into Chrome (which you already pointed out). I have done it, and it worked well. I don't think you would want to stream video over to it (might be choppy), but for sharing webpages or collaborating on a document, it worked fine.

The only downside I found was there didn't seem to be any way to make the Cast Receiver app full screen, but after putting the taskbar on Auto-hide, it was large enough for my purposes.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-turn-your-pc-into-a-chromecast-receiver/